# MSBuild is failing after Jenkins job is queued with ECONNREFUSED, url is not correct

Tags: jenkins, msbuild

I have been searching for the answer to this problem.  We just set up TFS2017 in our development lab, and I am working on integrating the Release Management with our Jenkins build environment.  I have successfully used MSBUILD to build SQL Server projects, but am running into an issue having MSBUILD queue a jenkins job and wait for it to complete.

An extract of the debug log from the build is below.  Note that in the line with createRootJob, the url is being passed, but has a forward slash before the :8080 port.

This build server is running Jenkins on the 8080 port, and has Visual Studio installed, as well as a build agent.  The TFS servers are different servers.

The Jenkins build does complete, but no feedback is received by the MSBUILD job.

I'm not sure what is trying to set up the callback from Jenkins to TFS, but it clearly is failing.  I'm not sure if the failure is a misconfiguration in Jenkins or in the TFS job.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

```
2017-01-12T05:09:22.3956535Z ##[debug]teamBuildPostData = {"url":"http://10.XX.YY.ZZ:8080/team-build/build/MCC_BuildTest?delay=0sec","form":{"json":"{\"team-build\":{\"System.Debug\":\"true\",\"Agent.BuildDirectory\":\"D:\\\\agent\\\\_work\\\\1\",\"Agent.HomeDirectory\":\"D:\\\\agent\",\"Agent.Id\":\"4\",\"Agent.MachineName\":\"CBA-FS1\",\"Agent.Name\":\"CBA-FS1\",\"Agent.WorkFolder\":\"D:\\\\agent\\\\_work\",\"Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory\":\"D:\\\\agent\\\\_work\\\\1\\\\a\",\"Build.BuildId\":\"6369\",\"Build.BuildNumber\":\"20170112.1\",\"Build.BuildUri\":\"vstfs:///Build/Build/6369\",\"Build.BinariesDirectory\":\"D:\\\\agent\\\\_work\\\\1\\\\b\",\"Build.DefinitionName\":\"Jenkins_BuildTest\",\"Build.DefinitionVersion\":\"5\",\"Build.QueuedBy\":\"Brad\",\"Build.QueuedById\":\"a47e4a97-b165-4a20-961a-1598b4b3c056\",\"Build.Repository.Clean\":\"false\",\"Build.Repository.LocalPath\":\"D:\\\\agent\\\\_work\\\\1\\\\s\",\"Build.Repository.Name\":\"MCC\",\"Build.Repository.Provider\":\"TfsVersionControl\",\"Build.Repository.Tfvc.Workspace\":\"ws_1_4\",\"Build.Repository.Uri\":\"http://ops-tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/\",\"Build.RequestedFor\":\"Brad\",\"Build.RequestedForId\":\"a47e4a97-b165-4a20-961a-1598b4b3c056\",\"Build.SourceBranch\":\"$/MCC/src-1.28.1\",\"Build.SourceBranchName\":\"src-1.28.1\",\"Build.SourcesDirectory\":\"D:\\\\agent\\\\_work\\\\1\\\\s\",\"Build.SourceVersion\":\"2691\",\"Build.StagingDirectory\":\"D:\\\\agent\\\\_work\\\\1\\\\a\",\"Build.Repository.Git.SubmoduleCheckout\":\"False\",\"Common.TestResultsDirectory\":\"D:\\\\agent\\\\_work\\\\1\\\\TestResults\",\"System.CollectionId\":\"30782aca-7b73-4bc1-974b-eb76fc3f951d\",\"System.DefaultWorkingDirectory\":\"D:\\\\agent\\\\_work\\\\1\\\\s\",\"System.DefinitionId\":\"21\",\"System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri\":\"http://ops-tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/\",\"System.TeamProject\":\"MCC\",\"System.TeamProjectId\":\"8531d7a1-5c3c-409d-a1e7-f5ce08b36461\",\"TF_BUILD\":\"True\"},\"parameter\":[{\"name\":\"target.config\",\"value\":\"test44\"}]}"},"strictSSL":true,"headers":{"Jenkins-Crumb":"a204374503ffe8fc12e604c393df0912"}}
2017-01-12T05:09:22.5206535Z ##[debug]submitJob().teamBuildRequestCallback(teamBuildPostData)
2017-01-12T05:09:22.5206535Z Jenkins job queued
2017-01-12T05:09:22.5206535Z ##[debug]createRootJob(): http://10.XX.YY.ZZ/:8080/queue/item/4/api/json
2017-01-12T05:09:23.5362554Z ##[debug]createRootJob().requestCallback()
2017-01-12T05:09:23.5362554Z Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.XX.YY.ZZ:80
2017-01-12T05:09:23.5362554Z ##[debug]connect ECONNREFUSED 10.XX.YY.ZZ:80
2017-01-12T05:09:23.5518798Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
2017-01-12T05:09:23.5518798Z ##[error]connect ECONNREFUSED 10.XX.YY.ZZ:80
2017-01-12T05:09:23.5518798Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]connect ECONNREFUSED 10.XX.YY.ZZ:80
2017-01-12T05:09:23.5675053Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]connect ECONNREFUSED 10.XX.YY.ZZ:80
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did anyone figure a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting a similar problem, where there was no feedback from the MSBuild job even though Jenkins completed successfully. Running the build in debug mode showed that likewise I had a connection error:

```
2017-02-23T23:22:15.6421740Z ##[debug]createRootJob(): http://localhost:8080/queue/item/162/api/json
2017-02-23T23:22:19.8729510Z ##[debug]createRootJob().requestCallback()
2017-02-23T23:22:19.8750960Z ##[debug]Error: socket hang up
```

I ended up resolving this issue by ensuring my Jenkins configuration URL was listed correct in the Jenkins settings: 
Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Jenkins Location > Jenkins URL

Comment: While working through and around this, I did some updates to both TFS and Jenkins.  Then saw your note, had a "d'oh" moment, and went and checked. Something had gotten munged in the jenkins entry.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.